# How can I make a GridViewItem as a draggable object instead of a DataTemplate in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a XAML file which should make it possible to drag GridViewItems inside a GridView. Now I'm using an ItemSource for the GridView items and a DataTemplate to show them in the way I want them to be shown. That works. The following problem occured: Since I started using DataTemplate, the GridViewItems are not draggable. I can only drag the DataTemplate. That's weird, so the only part I can use to drag, is the area left and right of the GridViewItems because this is used for margin.

Why is the DataTemplate the 'draggable' control instead of the GridViewItem? I have tried numerous fixes but none seem to work out well.. I can ofcourse make it work without a DataTemplate, but it's much cleaner to use it like this.

```
        <GridView Name="canvas" ItemsSource="{Binding GridviewItemList}" CanReorderItems="{Binding CanvasCanReorder}" CanDragItems="{Binding CanvasCanDrag}" ReorderMode="Enabled" AllowDrop="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="660" Height="110" IsSwipeEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MainPageItems">
                <GridViewItem Name="{x:Bind GvName}" Margin="13 0 15 0">
                    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="{x:Bind BdBackground, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TextBlock Height="60" Width="30" FontSize="40" Text="{x:Bind TbText, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="{x:Bind TbMargin, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </GridViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DragItemsCompleted">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasDragCompleted}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </GridView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `GridViewItem` in the `DataTemplate`, there are two `ListViewItemPresenter` in one `GridViewItem`. Please check it in the Live Visual Tree.

> In UWP apps for Windows 10, both ListViewItem and GridViewItem use ListViewItemPresenter; the GridViewItemPresenter is deprecated and you should not use it. ListViewItem and GridViewItem set different property values on ListViewItemPresenter to achieve different default looks.

For more info, please refer [Item containers and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/listview-item-templates).

If you want to set `Margin` to the `GridViewItem`, we should be able to set the `GridViewItem` style in the `GridView.ItemContainerStyle`.

For example:

```
 <GridView Name="canvas" ItemsSource="{Binding GridviewItemList}" CanReorderItems="{Binding CanvasCanReorder}" CanDragItems="{Binding CanvasCanDrag}" ReorderMode="Enabled" AllowDrop="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="660" Height="110" IsSwipeEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MainPageItems">
             <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="{x:Bind BdBackground, Mode=OneWay}">
                 <TextBlock Height="60" Width="30" FontSize="40" Text="{x:Bind TbText, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="{x:Bind TbMargin, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
             </Border>
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemTemplate>
     <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
             <Setter Property="Margin" Value="13 0 15 0"/>
         </Style>
     </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DragItemsCompleted">
             <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanvasDragCompleted}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
         </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
     </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </GridView>
```